# Using PHP to Print JSON and then save as a JSON file

Tags: php, xcode, json, afnetworking

I am currently using the following script to print a json file

```
<?PHP 

include ('connect.php');



$get_student = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY name asc");
$anArray = json_decode ($data);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_student)) {

$anArray[] = $row;

}
header("Content-type: application/json"); 
echo json_encode ($anArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
?>
```

I am then fetching the json file in xcode using AFNETWORKING and saving it into the document directory

```
  url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url/Json3.php"];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database"];

downloadOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[downloadOperation start];
```

I am then trying to read the downloaded document as a JSON file with the following

```
NSURL *JsonUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *JSONrequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:JsonUrl];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:JSONrequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {


    anArray = JSON;
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];
[operation start];
```

However AFNetworking gives me the following error line in log

Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0xa49f990 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=[

and then shows the text documents contents in the log

**QUESTION**

How do I make the PHP JSON Print, print a Application/Json document and not a text document?

Thanks

Comment: I guess before sending `header('Content-Type: application/json');` there occures an error in PHP.

Comment: Check for a _"headers already sent"_ warning.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen i have checked the headers file and can confirm that they have not already been sent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a headers already sent problem, in your "connect.php", at the very top, put

```
ob_start();
```

This will start outbut buffering which basically means, php doesnt send anything to the browser until everything is rendered (or until the buffer is sent, stopped etc..)

If its something else and you just want to save your data into a json file, you can use

```
file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($anArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Also, it could be a problem with the flags you are passing to the json_encode function. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ozzy, i have tried the above but to no prevail. Indeed the file_put_contents prints the JSON file in the correct format but saves it on the server as a seperate identity. What im trying to achieve is to make the php script print the correct document in the first instance

Answer (score 0):

Check content of connect.php that no spaces are after the php end tag,   or just remove  ?>

Comment: Thanks for your response David but after checking the connect doc i can confirm that no spaces are at the end of the php document

Answer (score 0):

Ok i didnt resolve the print issue but a simple line of code made it work

```
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
```

hope this helps somebody with a similar issue